# Allow only one application to connect to wcf service

Tags: security, wcf, authentication, authorization

I have one application and a wcf service hosted in a Windows service. Both are running on the same computer and I'm using netTcpBinding. I want my wcf service to be accessed only by my application only. How do I achieve this? Please help

Comment: As long as the client has the endpoint address information and service contract information about the server-side, the client can call the server by creating a channel. According to your intention, we can't create WCF service that it can only be called by the specified program. Any program can call WCF service as long as it has WCF server endpoint information and service contract. If you are worried about the security of the WCF service, you can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/security

Comment: Thank you very much Ding Peng. I am going with userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" to authorize only my client application to use the service methods.